# How to set up a layout using code and not XML

Tags: android

I'm learning to develop android apps and in the process I realized that there two ways to get a job done. Using xml or normal code. Suppose I want to change the position of a button, I'll be doing it in xml using align left/align centre etc., This will be done in the XML file. If I want to achieve the same through code, where should I place the code ? Inside which class ?

Comment: Please look into dynamic layouts. Use Google for instance. Here you will get downvoted because this type of questions are many here. Please look through the questions first

Comment: It is not about dynamic layout. I don't want use the XML file to edit my layout. I want to do it using java code. I just want to know where the code should be place. Is it inside the MainActivity ?

Comment: @user2798783: Yes, you need to place your code to edit your layout in the MainActivity.java file (referenced for your layout file).

Comment: Obviously inside main activity.

Comment: What will you achieve by creating buttons textviews and edittext dynamically ? First of all it is quite hard than xml, secondly , you app will not run any faster if you write in java instead of xml, thirdly it is very very hard to create as you cannot see the preview of the layout and it is also very irritating.

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to your question that I understand.
 1. Creating a whole layout file dynamically (without XML).
 2. Creating a layout through XML and changing the components positions and properties dynamically through your activity file.
Now, it's upto the developer what he wishes to choose.

To help you further, please view this [video link](http://www.parleys.com/#st=5&id=2191&sl=8) posted by the Android team.
It's all about layouts and includes how to layout apps using Java, not XML. However, you are warned that the android team wants you to use XML.

Answer (score 0):

The code will be placed in the same class as the class where you reference your xml code. Do a read up in your android docs for insight.